# Meteor CollectionFS: Make sure the image is uploaded before displaying

Tags: javascript, file-upload, meteor, amazon-s3

I am using the [CollectionFS](https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS) package with the S3 adapter and I've looked at a few different solutions but cannot get this to work right.

The problem: Even though the file/image is being uploaded to S3 successfully, the callback for a successful upload is triggered before it is safe to display the image. This causes a broken image to be displayed sometimes.

I found out about the `fileObj.once("uploaded", function(){})` callback but it seems "uploaded" basically means sending the image to the server. The S3 uploading does not happen by then. A temporary workaround I found is to just to just have `setTimeout` for 3-4 seconds but this is not reliable.

Here is my upload code:

```
FS.Utility.eachFile(event, function(file) {
    Session.set('profilePhotoUploaded', false);
    var newFile = new FS.File(file);
    newFile.metadata = {owner: Meteor.userId()};    

    ProfileImages.insert(newFile, function (err, fileObj) {
      if (err){
         console.log("error! - " + err);
      } else {
         // handle success depending what you need to do

        var userId = Meteor.userId();

        // This does NOT run when image is stored in S3. I think it runs when the image reached the app server.
        fileObj.once("uploaded", function () {

            // timeout of 3 seconds to make sure image is ready to be displayed 
            // --- This is not a good solution and it image does is not always ready
            setTimeout(function(){ 
                var uploadedImage = {
                  "profile.image.url": "/cfs/files/profileImages/" + fileObj._id
                };
                Meteor.users.update(userId, {$set: uploadedImage});

                Session.set('profilePhotoUploaded', true);
            }, 3000);  

            console.log("Done uploading!");
        });
     }
   });
});
```

Is there a different callback to check if the image has actually been stored in S3? I tried `fileObj.once("stored", function(){})` but that does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that `fileObj.hasStored("profileImages")` specifies exactly when the image is stored on S3. So after starting the upload process, I just start a timer every 1 second to check if it is saved. This might not be the best solution but this is what worked for me.

```
FS.Utility.eachFile(event, function(file) {
    Session.set('profilePhotoUploaded', false);
    var newFile = new FS.File(file);
    newFile.metadata = {owner: Meteor.userId()};    // TODO: check in deny that id is of the same user

    ProfileImages.insert(newFile, function (err, fileObj) {
      if (err){
         console.log("error! - " + err);
      } else {
         // handle success depending what you need to do

        var userId = Meteor.userId();

        // Timer every 1 second
        var intervalHandle = Meteor.setInterval(function () {
                                    console.log("Inside interval");
                                    if (fileObj.hasStored("profileImages")) {
                                        // File has been uploaded and stored. Can safely display it on the page. 
                                        var uploadedImage = {
                                          "profile.image.url": "/cfs/files/profileImages/" + fileObj._id
                                        };
                                        Meteor.users.update(userId, {$set: uploadedImage});

                                        Session.set('profilePhotoUploaded', true);

                                        // file has stored, close out interval
                                        Meteor.clearInterval(intervalHandle);
                                    }
                                }, 1000);
     }
   });
});
```

Comment: It sucks that there is no callback yet on the client side to tell the application that the file has been safely stored, but this code will have to do for now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that the `stored` hook will fire when the original image is saved on the server, so if you're creating multiple copies (thumbnails) this hook will fire before your thumbnails are stored. You can check which version of the thumbnail was stored by checking the storeName argument. In the server side file, where you define the `ProfileImages` collection add the following code, replacing `'profilePhotoLarge'` with the name assigned to your `FS.Store.S3` store:

```
ProfileImages.on('stored', Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(fileObj, storeName) {
    if (storeName === 'profilePhotoLarge') {
        Meteor.users.update({_id: fileObj.metadata.owner}, {
            $set: {
                'profile.image.url': 'https://your AWS region domain/your bucket name/your folder path/' + fileObj._id + '-' +fileObj.name()
            }
        });
    }
}, function() { console.log('Failed to bind environment'); }));
```

For profile photos I created an S3 bucket and set the permissions to allow anyone to read the files, so I'm storing the URL to the image on S3, which may not be correct in your case. Since the user object is reactive on the client side this update will cause the profile photo to update automatically.

Comment: Actually, I thought this really would work. But it does not. And I think the reason is mentioned https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS/issues/351 - "stored" event on a collection on the server should work properly now. You can also now do fileObj.on("stored", func) on the server and fileObj.on("uploaded", func) on the client. Eventually we plan to emit "stored" on the client for collections and fileObjs, but that is trickier and not implemented yet.

Comment: So I am trying to get a "Stored" callback on the client. I am guessing this would work on the server side. I think I have found a workaround though using Timers.